# Questions about different string, int, and hex types

Tags: python, string, hex, type-conversion

I am confused about some of the following number representations:

1. `a = 0xff`    # A hex number
2. `a = 'ff'`    # ASCII ff
3. `a = '\xff'`  # What is this?
4. `a = b'ff'`   # What is this?

How can I convert these types to each other?

I.e., 1->2, 2->1, 1->3, 3->1, etc.

Comment: `int`, `str`, `str`, `str`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is appears to be a quiz for the readers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question. I meant to ask how to convert from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** is a number,

**2** is a string with two chars 'f',

**3** is a string with a single char,

**4** equals to **2** in python2 but not in python3.

**1 ←→ 3**:

```
In [440]: chr(0xff)
Out[440]: '\xff'

In [441]: ord('\xff')
Out[441]: 255
```

**4 ←→ 2:**

```
#python2:
In [444]: b'ff'=='ff'
Out[444]: True

#python3: ('bytes' is a builtin type different from 'str' in py3)
In [2]: type(b'ff')
Out[2]: builtins.bytes

In [3]: b'ff'=='ff'
Out[3]: False
```

**UPDATE:**

**1 ←→ 2:**

```
In [455]: hex(a)[2:]
Out[455]: 'ff'
```

**3 ←→ 2:** 3->1->2， do it yourself ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. What about 1 <-> 2 and 3 <-> 2?

Comment: 1->2 i can do a.encode("hex")